# How to debug Icalendar URL in Google Calendar

Tags: testing

I'm developing a ICalendar service. If i add the URL in outlook everything looks correct, but if i import the URL in Google calendar it does not show the description of event.

As google calendar takes up to 24 hours to sync with external calendars it makes it very difficult to test/debug what might be the cause.

Any idea how to solve this or what might be the reason google calendar wont show the description?